# A UITabBar like this

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbar

I wondering how I can make a UITabBat like this:
[image]

The height of this is more than the stand UITabBar and also the icons are larger. Also the arrow on top.

I tried changing the height but it looks really bad. The icons aren't centred vertically. Also I couldn't change the background.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest several things;

1. Check out the core animation videos from this years wwdc, you can use it to create effects like the triangle and move it back and forth. Then write your own tab bar controller class.
2. you could also consider a third party library like http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/tabbarkit